# Excel VBA - Run Time Error 13 Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

I'm creating a task list style excel sheet in which people are assigned tasks and can use the sheet as a progress tracker.

Once a task is completed, a person marks it off as completed and the sheet pops up with a message box asking whether a change reference number is needed.

However, when I filter by say, the person who completed the task, and try to add a new row for a new task I get the Run Time Error 13 Type Mismatch. I think it's because my VBA is constantly checking for the status of the task to be completed, so when you create a blank row, there's nothing in the status column.

Here's the below code that's highlighted with the error message.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim answer
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H5:H1000")) Is Nothing Then
        If (Target.Value) = "Completed" Then
            answer = MsgBox("Do you need to add a change reference?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Change      Reference Reminder")
            If answer = vbYes Then
                MsgBox "Add in the column to the right", , ("Change Reference Tip")
            Else
                'do nothing'
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Active.Sheet`? What's that meant to do? And VBA should tell you the line number the problem occurred on, from memory.

Comment: Command without any action^^

Comment: At which point are you adding in an extra row?

Comment: sorry I left the active.sheet in by mistake. That should be a 'do nothing' comment. I filter the task list by the name of the person the task is attributed to and when I try to add another row to add another task, so the row's are blank it gives me an error message and highlights the "If (Target.Value) = "Completed" Then" line in VBA

Comment: I tested your code. It ran as expected, no errors. Can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: It's a filtered sheet. So i think the problem is that when it adds a new row, it is constantly checking for the completed column to say completed, so when a new row is created for a new task, the completed column is blank

Comment: I fixed the problem. I think it was due to me having the VBA on the sheet rather than in a module. As soon as I put it into a module it functions correctly. Thanks for all your help everyone!

Comment: Actually the code is not working entirely when put into a module that's why I wasn't getting an error message

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here; too many to describe in a comment.

1. First of all, the `Worksheet_Change` sheet macro is triggered by an *event*, specifically when one or more cells' contents change. If you want to avoid heavy processing when you insert a row (subsequently changing the values of many cells), you need it to kick out if `Target` is more than a single cell. Typically, including `If Target.cells.count > 1 then exit sub` as the first line is sufficient to accomplish this. This is especially important as you want to compare a single changed cell's value to *Completed*.
2. Your code as supplied doesn't actually change anything but it looks like at some point it will be intended to. In order that changing a cell's value does not launch a second iteration of the same `Worksheet_Change` event maco (subsequently trying to run on top of itself) you would halt event handling temporarily and restart it just before leaving the macro.
3. If you turn off events, you need error handling so that they are turned back on in case of an error. Errors can occur to the best written code procedure and you want to catch and report the error to somewhere like the *Immediate window* then turn the event handling back on before safely exiting the event macro.
4. Minor point but I never `Dim` a variable until my boolean conditions dictate that I am actually going to use it.

With these 3½ things in mind, the sample code provided might be better as,

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H5:H1000")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo Erreur
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If LCase(Target.Value) = "completed" Then
            Dim answer As Variant
            answer = MsgBox("Do you need to add a change reference?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Change      Reference Reminder")
            If answer = vbYes Then
                MsgBox "Change references are added in the column to the right." _
                  & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Let's go there now.", vbOKOnly, "Change Re ference Tip"
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            Else
                'do nothing'
            End If
        End If
    End If
    GoTo Fìn
Erreur:
    Debug.Print Err
Fìn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I've added one line of code that moved the user to the cell one column to the right of the cell that triggered the event.